# How to make GridView Scrolling smooth?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am building a Grid of images and I am using customScrollBar with Sliver to make it cool .
But on scrolling I am not getting smooth scrolling .

Here is my code for body.

```dart
body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            title: Text('Gallery'),
            expandedHeight: SizeConfig.blockHeight * 30.0,
            //backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            floating: false,
            pinned: true,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              background: Image.asset('images/test.jpg',fit: BoxFit.fill,)
            ),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                bottom: Radius.circular(10),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverGrid(
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 4,
                mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                childAspectRatio: 1.0),
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Cell();
              },
              childCount: 100,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

And at one place I am using Cell widget which is nothing but a container and it takes an image .
To note that the size of image is just 37 KB . So image size is not causing the problem I guess .
Any suggestions to make scrolling smooth .

Comment: are you using different images in every grid item? is scrolling smooth if you use just the same `Image.asset(...)`?

Comment: @pskink right now I am just testing so I am not using different images but in future I'll use .

Comment: so now you use just the same `Image.asset(...)`?

Comment: Yes @pskink . I am using those `Image.asset('images/test.jpg')` inside the Cell  widget too .

Comment: Try running the application in release mode, debug mode is usually more sluggish, that might be your issue.

Comment: @AlexCollette I tried it in release mode too but it was still same :( .

Comment: Are you on an emulator? Im trying it on my machine and the animation looks smooth

Comment: and did you try (just for testing) to remove `Image.asset` and leave just `Container`?

Comment: @AlexCollette I am running this app on machine whole time but it is still lagging . Actually it seems like there is a jerk on scrolling . I mean it just feels like they are getting stopped for moment then again scrolling . Did you get the same thing ?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Cd1OQ4Vt_i26Meo8bEPod7SHykQIjWVt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Brijesh, mine feels completely smooth, not sure why that would be happening. Edit, I am not currently populating the Cells with images. Ill do that and get back to you

Comment: That @pskink I have uploaded a video of the app on my drive and given the link above . You can see that .

Comment: @AlexCollette I have posted a link of video of the app . You will notice that when I'll open the notification panel how smooth it is but while I am scrolling in the app it is jerking .

Comment: Im still getting pretty smooth scrolling, even with images. One thing I found that others have said can help is to set `physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics ()` for the customScrollView. Not sure if it will help, but worth a shot. It might also be worth looking into precacheImage, so its not having to load the image right before displaying the widget.

Comment: @AlexCollette thanks a lot . I'll try your ideas .

Comment: @AlexCollette found the culprit . Actually in my Cell code I was doing `fit : Boxfit.fill` and it was making the whole thing slow ..Thanks a lot for your help . Now I'll do precaching of images then I think it'll work fine .

Comment: @pskink Thanks for your help . I found the issue .

Comment: Awesome! What was the issue?

Comment: @AlexCollette Actually in my Cell code I was doing `fit : Boxfit.fill` and it was making the whole thing slow ..Thanks a lot for your help . Now I'll do precaching of images then I think it'll work fine .

Comment: you dont need any "precaching of images" - it is done automatically with `ImageCache` class - the docs say: *"Class for caching images.

Implements a least-recently-used cache of up to 1000 images, and up to 100 MB. The maximum size can be adjusted using maximumSize and maximumSizeBytes. [...] Generally this class is not used directly. The ImageProvider class and its subclasses automatically handle the caching of images."*

Comment: Thanks @pskink surely I'll try it .